# Empty Datagridview cell with bound datasourse

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with "Type" and "Value" columns. The user selects a data type, and then enters a value compatible with that type, some types (e.g. "Text") accept any string. Other types (e.g. "Yes/No") are restricted to a list of possible values. For each row, I set the cell in the "Value" column to be either a Textbox for freeform types, or a combobox for list types. The DataGridView is bound to a DataTable.

The problem comes in if the user enters a value for one type, but then switches the row to a different type for which the current value is not allowed. No matter what I try, I cannot clear the Value cell. Then when I assign a combobox to the cell, I get a DataError, because the current value of the cell is incompatible. How can I clear the value before changing the cell from a textbox to a combobox?

```
public enum DataType 
{
    Text,
    YesNo
}

public class IndexedItem 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID {get; set; }

    public string strID 
    {
        get { return ID.ToString(); }
    }       

    //constructors & other methods;
}

public static DataTable ParameterTable;
public List<IndexedItem> YesNoList;
```

In the form constructor (dgvInputs is the DataGridView):

```
ParameterTable = new DataTable("ParameterTable");
ParameterTable.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(DataType));
ParameterTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

YesNoList = new List<IndexedItem>();
YesNoList.Add(new IndexedItem("Yes", 1));
YesNoList.Add(new IndexedItem("No", 0));

var D = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgvInputs.Columns[0];
D.ValueMember = "Value";
D.DisplayMember = "Display";
D.DataSource = new DataType[] { 
        DataType.Text,
        DataType.YesNo
}.Select(x => new { Display = x.ToString(), Value = (int)x }).ToList();

BindingSource ParamSource = new BindingSource();
ParamSource.DataSource = ParameterTable;
dgvInputs.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgvInputs.DataSource = ParamSource;
dgvInputs.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Type";
dgvInputs.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Value";
```

And Events:

```
private void dgvInputs_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (dgvInputs.IsCurrentCellDirty) {
        dgvInputs.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}

private void dgvInputs_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
   if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0) {
      var cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgvInputs[0, e.RowIndex];
      if (cb.Value != null && cb.Value != DBNull.Value) {
         DataType Type = (DataType)cb.Value;
         dgvInputs[1, e.RowIndex].Value = string.Empty;
         dgvInputs.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
         switch (Type) {
            case DataType.YesNo:
               dgvInputs[1, e.RowIndex].Dispose();
               var newBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
               newBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
               newBox.ValueMember = "strID";
               newBox.DataSource = YesNoList;
               dgvInputs[1, e.RowIndex] = newBox;
               break;
            default:
               dgvInputs[1, e.RowIndex] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
               break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you have it set to "text" and enter something arbitrary, then switch to "YesNo", it gives an error "System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.", that will reappear any time the cursor is over the cell. Changing it back to a text row causes the original value to reappear.

I am assuming that the problem is that the value is saved in ParameterTable, but I can't get it to propagate my clearing of the original value to ParameterTable. I've tried `null` and `DBNull.Value` instead of `string.Empty`, but neither one made any difference. I added the "CommitEdit" line in hopes of getting it to make the change, but that made no difference either.

**Edit:**
As it turns out, the problem was this code that I had in the cell change event:

```
string Default = dgvInputs[4, e.RowIndex].Value as string;
// code switching out text box and combo box above
try 
{
    dgvInputs[4, e.RowIndex].Value = Default;
} catch (Exception e2) {
    MessageBox.Show(e2.GetType().ToString());
}
```

The idea had been to preserve the value if possible, and I had the messagebox to show me the specific exception I needed to catch, as I was not sure. But apparently this assignment does not immediately induce the exception. That only occurs later, apparently during some other event I am not handling.

It is obvious in hindsight that I should have included this code in the sample. I have no idea now how I overlooked it. My apologies to everybody I led on a wild goose chase by leaving out the critical information. I do appreciate all of your assistance.

Comment: DBType Type = (DataType)cb.Value; doesn't compile.

Comment: I copied the code, fixed some compile errors, run, select both types and input or select values, did not pop up any error message.

Comment: @LeiYang - I severelly truncated the code for the example, and tried to change "DBType" to "DataType" because there is a "DbType" in some stock library (which I only discovered after I had chosen my name) and didn't want to confuse on it. I'll have to try the truncated example here myself. Though I tried not to do so, I may have removed something relevant.

Comment: @LeiYang - I've tried it, and you are right: the code here works for me too. So the problem must be in something that I didn't include. I'll have to hunt it down.

Comment: The solution you're trying to implement is usually done via [PropertyGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The reason this hasn't got much attention is probably due to the unusual implementation of DataGridView, you might want to consider changing the approach.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the PropertyGrid does not at all encapsulate what I am trying to do. Users need to be able to add or delete new rows. There are other columns than the two discussed here. The only variance from normal DataGridView behavior I have is wanting occasionally to restrict values in one column based on the value in a different column of the same row.

Comment: @LeiYang - FYI, I found the problem, It is decribed in an addendum to the OP. Thanks for testing it and letting me know that the sample code worked. That was what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not with clearing the value but with the YesNoList.

The grid compbobox tries to find the value for the current record and there is no empty neither null value in your YesNoList.

You will even get an error if you try to add a new record and first set the DataType without setting the Value.

You can solve this by either adding an empty item to your YesNoList or by setting a default value to the existing record when switching DataType.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but why does it not raise an error if I choose a YesNo box first, even though no data has been entered into the field? Or if I don't assign anything to the textbox before switching over to the combobox? If this were the cause, I should have errors in those cases as well.

Comment: This happens whenever a new row is added. The grid will look in the dropdown list to find the current value of the cell. In case the new row came from the dropdown there is already a value from the list, if the new row came from another cell then the value is whatever the default value of the column in the datatable is set (in your case null). the null value in not in the dropdown list and you get an error.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I am seeing. I get no error when I add a new row by a different column even though the combobox is null. I get no error if the textbox was empty before I switch the type to bring up the combobox. even though the combobox is null when it appears. I only get an error if the textbox has text in it before the switch. Also, as noted by Lei Yang, the simplified code I provided here actually works, which it would not do if this were the problem. I'll have to figure out what I excised that I should not have when I created the post.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your sample, but I never got any error message! My next guess would be that the previous value entered fails the validation test, and therefore it is not committed to the underline datatable. Did you try to Cancel the current edit instead of committing it?

Comment: That's what Lei Yang pointed out in his comments. The truncated sample code I posted works. It turns out the problem was a try-catch block that I thought was not the issue since it wasn't catching an exception. But it turns out it was setting the stage for a later exception to occur in a different event. I had excised the try-catch block as part of reducing the code to a reasonble size to post. My thanks to you for your attention to this, and apologies for accidently leaving out what was important.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I know below does not specifically answer your question as it states, but the example may help you out. Consider having two controllers in one cell.

---

Original

I am not sure if this will help you or not, but I tried to make a very basic program that you discussed. A dataset is created with 2 entries. The first column is the DataType, the second is of Value. If the DataType Text is chosen, the Value cell turns into a Textbox. If the DataType Yes/No is chosen, it hides the Textbox and shows a DropDownList.  The idea is to hide one component when not needed.

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace DataGridViewBounds
{
  public partial class _Default : Page
  {
    public enum DataType
    {
      Text,
      YesNo
    }

    public class IndexedItem
    {
      public string Name
      { get; set; }
      public int ID
      { get; set; }
      public string strID
      { get { return ID.ToString(); } }
    }

    protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
        Bind();
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; ++i)
      {
        bool ShowText = ((DropDownList)dg.Items[i].Cells[0].Controls[1]).SelectedValue.Equals("text");
        ((DropDownList)dg.Items[i].Cells[1].Controls[1]).Visible = !ShowText;
        ((TextBox)dg.Items[i].Cells[1].Controls[3]).Visible = ShowText;
      }

    }

    private void Bind ()
    {
      DataTable ParameterTable = new DataTable("ParameterTable");
      ParameterTable.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
      ParameterTable.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(DataType));
      ParameterTable.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

      List<ListItem> YesNoList = new List<ListItem>();    // Should be ListItem, not IndexedItem
      YesNoList.Add(new ListItem("Yes", "1"));
      YesNoList.Add(new ListItem("No", "0"));

      DataRow row = ParameterTable.NewRow();
      row["Type"] = DataType.Text;
      row["Value"] = "Some text";

      DataRow row2 = ParameterTable.NewRow();
      ParameterTable.Rows.Add(row);
      row2["Type"] = DataType.YesNo;
      row2["Value"] = "false";
      ParameterTable.Rows.Add(row2);

      dg.DataSource = ParameterTable;
      dg.DataBind();
      dg.ShowHeader = true;
      dg.Visible = true;

      for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; ++i)
      { // Showing 2 ways to bind the DropDownList items
        ((DropDownList)dg.Items[i].Cells[0].Controls[1]).Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "text"));
        ((DropDownList)dg.Items[i].Cells[0].Controls[1]).Items.Add(new ListItem("Yes/No", "bool"));

        ((DropDownList)dg.Items[i].Cells[1].Controls[1]).DataSource = YesNoList;
        ((DropDownList)dg.Items[i].Cells[1].Controls[1]).DataBind();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the Default.aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DataGridViewBounds._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:DataGrid ID="dg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Type">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddListType" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Label id="TypeLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>    
    </ItemTemplate>  
  </asp:TemplateColumn>

  <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Value">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddListValue" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox id="ValueLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>

</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

This is the best I could do at the moment without seeing more of the code, but may you can use it. One suggestion, dgvInputs_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged appears to commit code. I am assuming this is SQL code. You may want to wait until committing until a final 'Submit' button or 'Accept Changes' button has been pressed so that you don't have to call SQL so much, but also if there is an error that occurs between the start of the first SQL call and the last. If an interruption occurs between the two, you may not necessarily want to commit.

Comment: This is a WinForms application, not a webpage, but I'll look into whether the idea is translatable. Perhaps it can be done in WPF, but I am barely more than aware of the existance of WPF and would rather avoid having to learn a new paradigm to handle this if I can.

Comment: There is no SQL, just the datatable. THe "commit" was part of code I borrowed from other posts (whether in SO or some other forum, I don't remember) about how to have textboxes and comboboxes in the same column. I am not sure of why it was there.

Comment: Now that I have a working sample to experiment with (thanks to Lei Yang's comments on the OP), I found that the point of the DirtyCell commit event is that the textbox/combobox switch occurs as soon as the Type is changed. Without this event, it doesn't occur until the Type cell loses focus.